# How can I make Jquery code work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script for display of Google suggestions. The script also allows to come down in the suggested list using the arrow keys. When you do so the "text" is filled within the input field. The code for this is:

```
$("#inp").live("keyup", function(e) {
    var search_terms = $("li.current").text();
    if(e.keyCode==40)
    {
     $("#inp").val(search_terms);
    }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
    {
     $("#inp").val(search_terms);
    }
});
```

The complete script is over here: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eququd/2/edit)

The problem is that IE8 does not support "oninput" so first of all please test this in IE and replace "oninput" with "onpropertychange" which is an IE only event (so it seems) After doing that you will notice that the script does not respond proper when coming down in the suggestion list. However if you remove the above code than all works very well. But I really need the above code to function in IE, so what should I change in order to make it work properly?

Comment: The "onpropertychange" event object doens't include a `keyCode` property, because it isn't a keyboard event - it has nothing to do with user input at all, in fact. So `e.keyCode` is undefined or null, and never equals an arrow key code. I'd say you shouldn't use either `oninput` or `onpropertychange` since the 1st isn't cross-browser (as you found), and the 2nd has nothing to do with keyboard events. Use the keyup event instead (which you're already using anyway). I'm not a jQuery guy, though, so I can't give you the exact code, but it's too not hard to mimic the behavior of oninput

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I didn't know that onpropertychange has nothing to do with keybord.

Comment: No prob. `onpropertychange`'s purpose is to listen for when a property (variable) on a object changes. In other words, it's entirely to do with changes happening "within javascript" - the changes may be caused by the user, but basically anything that changes an object's properties will trigger it. When you start typing in a field, a bunch of that field's properties can change, so it seems like it's the same as `oninput`, but in fact it's a "side-effect", so to speak. That said, it can do the trick in some cases, but here I'd personally go for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating:) Excellent explanation

Answer (score 0):

update jquery to latest version :P